# Loop through two dataframes that have the same column headings to find similar rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am looking at comparing traffic at different intersections year over year. One file has info for October-December for 2017 and the other has January-October 2018. I want to compare the data points for October 2017 and October 2018. The only problem is that these files don't have all the same entries. Currently, the datetime is in format 2018-10-30 18:15:00 so I need to find matches that are the exact same except the fourth digit on the year (2017 vs. 2018), they ALSO need to match on the corresponding intersection_name value. Hopefully, I am left with something that gives me all the 2017 and 2018 rows in one dataframe that have two entries for each time (one from 2017 and 2018 and for the same intersection).

I have tried lots of things including the "merge" technique with the "on" column being on "intersection" and "date" but that just creates more columns than I need and ultimately does not solve the problem. I have broken up the two CSV's so they only include October and tried to match on "day" and "intersection_name" but this didn't work either.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import csv
import datetime

#read files in
df1 = pd.read_csv('detailed-traffic-pedestrian-volumes-2017.csv') 
df2 = pd.read_csv('detailed-traffic-pedestrian-volumes-2018.csv')
df1['datetime_bin'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['datetime_bin'])
df2['datetime_bin'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['datetime_bin'])

df1.rename(columns={'sum': 'volume'}, inplace=True)

df1['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['datetime_bin']).year
df1['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['datetime_bin']).month
df1['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df1['datetime_bin']).day


df2['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['datetime_bin']).year
df2['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['datetime_bin']).month
df2['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['datetime_bin']).day

df1 = df1.loc[(df1['month'] == 10) & (df1['classification'] == 
'Bicycles')]
df2 = df2.loc[(df2['month'] == 10) & (df2['classification'] == 
'Bicycles')] # days are listed as YYYY-MM-DD

common = df1.merge(df2,how = 'inner', on= 
['intersection_name','day'])
print(common.head())
```

I am looking for something that outputs all the rows in October for both years so that I have something to compare it to. i.e. same time except for different years AND same intersection value. The above code leaves me with excessive columns and I believe other issues as well. Bonus points for being able to tweak the days so that I am comparing a  Friday vs. a Friday instead of just October 10th to October 10th. There are definitely problems with my attempt. Ideally, I'd like to keep the full datetime as an index and not have to break it up into days to find the match.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer to this link on how to ask a question that will get you better responses & good answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  . Can you post some portion of dataframe representing the input & also expected output